# Executing a cURL script in Informatica

Tags: curl, cookies, informatica, informatica-cloud

I have a cURL script.  It logs into URL#1, populate a cookies.txt file, and uses that cookies.txt file to download an Excel file from URL #2.

```
    curl -c cookies.txt -X POST https://sso.URL.com/api/authenticateTfa -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data {"userId":"myUserID","password":"myPassword","appKey":"DOWNLOADFILE"}
    curl -b cookies.txt -O https://downloads2.URL.com/Reports/Some_Excel_File_2020_10_27.xlsx
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in Informatica Cloud?  I have researched this and I cannot figure it out.  I have set up a connection using a Swagger file to  `https://sso.URL.com`, which will get me a  message back saying "The test for this connection was successful" when I click Test Connection.

I don't know where to go after that. Do I use it inside of a synchronization task somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Service` to invoke a shell command. [Here](https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-application-integration/current-version/2----design/designing-processes/system-service-actions/run-a-shell-command.html) is the documentation and [here](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/562974) you can find a knowlegebase article with an example.